# Do the odd numbers modulo $2^n$ form a field?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

Do the odd numbers modulo $2^n$ form a field (of order $2^{n-1}$) for some $n$?  For $n$ a power of 2?

If so, this would be quite useful for cryptography.

Comment: Under what operations?

Comment: Of course this set is not closed under the normal modular addition. They do form a multiplicative group under the normal modular multiplication.

Comment: If $n\gt 1$, look at $1+1$.

Comment: Also, $0$ is not included because it is even.

Comment: What about $x + y - q \mod 2^n$ for some constant $q$ as the addition function?

Comment: If a field has $2^{n-1}$ elements, it is necessarily a vector space over $\Bbb{F}_2$. Therefore each element must be its own additive inverse. So the new addition rule, denote it $\oplus$, must satisfy $x\oplus x=\tilde{0}$, where $\tilde{0}$ is the additive neutral element. Anyway, you must have 
$$x\oplus x=y\oplus y$$ for all elements $x,y$.

Comment: The (residue classes of) odd numbers do form a group under multiplication. That group is known to be a direct product of a cyclic group of order two, and a cyclic group of order $2^{n-2}$ generated by $-1$ and $5$ respectively. You might think that using the larger cyclic subgroup generated by $5$ could be useful for some crypto purposes. Unfortunately, in a  cyclic group of  order a power of two the discrete logarithm is easy to calculate, so things like Diffie-Hellman based on that group are totally unsecure.

Comment: Of course, we can turn any finite set of cardinality $2^{n-1}$ into a field by porting the structure of a standard version of such a finite field using some bijection between the two sets. But that won't do anything useful.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I am not interested in discrete logarithms.  I am interested in almost-universal hash functions.